# Visual Studio 2008 c++ linker refuses to link?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I am banging my head against a wall here.

All i want is to link a static .lib file in a cpp windows forms application! So, i have an include folder in my project folder that holds header files for that .lib (lib is Yaml-cpp if someone wonders). And i have a lib folder that has the .lib files for that library.

I tested it on a blank project

1.I make a new windows forms project in VS2008, in C++.

2.I go to project properties - c/c++ general and additional include directories that have yaml-cpp header files

3.I go to linker and add path to my lib directory

4.I go to linker - input and add my .lib file

5.I check linker command line and it contains my .lib file so it must be all set.

6.Then i write the sample code in an onbutton function body (which appears in form1.h fie).

Sample code is from here http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument and its just as simple as:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "yaml.h"
```

and then:

```
std::ifstream fin("test.yaml");
YAML::Parser parser(fin);

YAML::Node doc;
while(parser.GetNextDocument(doc)) {
    //do nothing yet
}
```

7.And then i compile and have 10 "unresolved externals".

I have looked into another project that uses same library, and it has exactly same directory structure, same name of .lib added in linker - input - additional dependencies, same .lib and .h files. And it works for that project- but it doesnt work for me.

What in the world is wrong?

EDIT: I tried making new windows 32 console application and it worked correctly. I then tried to make another fresh windows forms application and it failed.

It is confirmed now. Same steps for linking a library work in console application and fail in windows forms application. WHY?

Comment: Please can you include the specific linker error messages? (my initial guess is that the .lib references other .libs and you haven't included them all in your linker settings)

Comment: yes they are huge though.... and to clarify, i checked another c++ project that uses same library and it didnt link anything except that one lib i also linked (yaml-cppd.lib). there is another yaml-cpp.lib file but it wasnt linked by that project and that project worked just fine... and linking that second lib doesnt help anyway

Comment: 1>test_yaml_cpp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000036) "public: bool __clrcall YAML::Parser::GetNextDocument(class YAML::Node &)" (?GetNextDocument@Parser@YAML@@$$FQAM_NAAVNode@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test_yaml_cpp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test_yaml_cpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Comment: 1>test_yaml_cpp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000037) "public: __clrcall YAML::Node::~Node(void)" (??1Node@YAML@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test_yaml_cpp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test_yaml_cpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Comment: 1>test_yaml_cpp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000038) "public: __clrcall YAML::Node::Node(void)" (??0Node@YAML@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test_yaml_cpp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test_yaml_cpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Comment: 1>test_yaml_cpp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000039) "public: __clrcall YAML::Parser::~Parser(void)" (??1Parser@YAML@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test_yaml_cpp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test_yaml_cpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Comment: 1>test_yaml_cpp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00003A) "public: __clrcall YAML::Parser::Parser(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??0Parser@YAML@@$$FQAM@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test_yaml_cpp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test_yaml_cpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Comment: 1>test_yaml_cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall YAML::Parser::~Parser(void)" (??1Parser@YAML@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test_yaml_cpp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test_yaml_cpp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Comment: ah, i see. Well, there are also four of those unresolved external symbol errors there and then a "10 unresolved externals" conclusion

Comment: can you also provide your linker command line?

Comment: non working (windows forms app): 
/OUT:"C:\Documents and Settings\...\Projects\test_win32_forms_yaml\Debug\test_win32_forms_yaml.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"deps\lib" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\test_win32_forms_yaml.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /PDB:"C:\Documents and Settings\Истребитель\Мои документы\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test_win32_forms_yaml\Debug\test_win32_forms_yaml.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:"main" /DYNAMICBASE /FIXED:No /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT libyaml-cppmdd.lib

Comment: working (console app):
/OUT:"C:\...\Debug\test_win32_console_yaml.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"deps\lib" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\test_win32_console_yaml.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"c:\...\Projects\test_win32_console_yaml\Debug\test_win32_console_yaml.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT libyaml-cppmdd.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Comment: had to omit long paths since it wouldnt fit into the character limit - where i left \...\ its basically a long path for user folder\visual studio folder\project folder

Comment: the libpath is deps\lib, do you have a copy of libyaml-cppmdd.lib in deps\lib under your new windows project?

Comment: both projects contain same include/lib files. In fact, i doubted that it was reading the file and tried adding x to the file name - it immediatey complained that file does not exist. So in fact both files do exist and are accessed (in some way) (or at least checked for existance)

Comment: what is the full directory path to the lib?

Comment: try replacing deps\lib with the full path to libyaml-cppmdd.lib..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done seems correct from your explanation, let's do some blind troubleshooting.

1. Try giving full path instead of relative path for library path and additional include directories. (but as u said that the file is getting read, that should be the problem.)
2. If you are using a copy of original `libyaml-cppmdd.lib` and its include file, check whether the header file that gets included is of the same version as the lib.
3. Check whether there are any functions in any part of the code that is having a declaration but no definition.
4. Check whether you're accessing any private functions from the library.

Please read this Microsoft article on [Troubleshooting UnResolved External Symbol error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138400).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well yea, problem is that win 32 console application WORKS with same lib, same paths, same include files! But windows forms application does NOT work (same paths, same include files, same sample code executed). So we can drop 1,2,3,4 as irrelevant :( since they all "pass" in win 32 console app. So it must be something wrong with windows forms appication?

Comment: check whether you are using any win32 libraries. Try including `<windows.h>`. Right-click the project, Properties, Linker, Input. Remove the $(NoInherit) from the Additional Dependencies setting. If you use VS2010 then put "user32.lib" in that setting.

Comment: Also try setting /clr mode to normal (plain /clr mode)

Comment: If none of these worked, try nesting the library function declarations in include file with [extern "C"](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1143/). (probably the last arrow in my quiver :D)